# Do we need replay cache in kerberos

Tags: security, networking, kerberos

Since kerberos already have timestamp in authentication process, why do we need replay cache?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Kerberos_protocol.svg

Comment: This is not a programming question. Please check out [security.se] and fill in "kerberos" and "cache" into the search box. If you're going to ask there, please include the Kerberos version number.

Comment: Admittedly you're doing something horribly horribly wrong if you're using anything other than Kerb 5, so version number is a bit redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Timestamp isn't a unique identifier of a request. A request is ticket + authenticator, where the *authenticator* is unique per request. There's nothing stopping a client from creating two separate requests with separate authenticators, but keeping the same timestamp and sending them off to a service.

This is in fact quite common in multi-threaded or high-speed operations or cases where sessions are just getting started up. In fact, it's almost guaranteed to happen to you regularly because the time precision isn't particularly high, in the scheme of things.

So therefore you use the authenticator as a replay check, which contains a unique-per-request nonce (and optionally session key). If you've ever seen this authenticator before you absolutely must treat the request as a replay.

The second issue is that of multiple [load-balanced] servers. If you fire a request to server (A) and then fire that same identical request to server (B), that second one is a replay. If you're purposefully doing this then you're likely asking for two requests one right after another, which might have the same timestamp with separate authenticators and fired off to separate servers.

Ideally you'd have a shared cache between servers so they can check, but in practice no one ever does this.

So in short whether you should cache it is a function of whether you *absolutely* need to guarantee protection against replay. If you don't, then timestamp *is* good enough. If you *do*, then the you need a proper cache, ideally shared between servers.